# Is there a way to enable OpenType font features (specifically for Monaspace)

Tags: fonts, linux

I'm currently running Emacs 28.2 on Debian 12 (Doom core v3.0.0-pre, Doom modules v23.12.0-pre). I have checked for harfbuzz support and have ligature.el installed.

I recently found [Monaspace](https://monaspace.githubnext.com), and would like to use some of its font features like texture healing and ligatures, and am having trouble finding out if I can enable these features or not. I read [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/60311/how-to-enable-opentype-features-in-font-spec) question on the forum and it seems like I can search for a font with those features, but am unsure how to use them.

I believe I'm looking for "contextual alternate" and "stylistic set" support, but searching online just pulls up Emacs alternative SEO sites.

If I set my font to FiraCode Nerd Font, ligatures work automatically without configuration.